# VB.NET - Navigate webpage with specified user-agent?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to change current user gaent to different user-agent. This one naviagtes the webpage, however, doesnt change the user-agent.

```
    Dim webBrowser1 As Object
    webBrowser1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.org", Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent: blabla")
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a System.Net.Webclient instead and give it the wanted headers.

```
Imports System.Net

Module Module1
    Sub Main()


        ' Resource acquisition statement.
        Using client As New WebClient
            ' Set one of the headers.
            client.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/4.0"

            ' Download data as byte array.
            Dim arr() As Byte = client.DownloadData("http://www.dotnetperls.com/")

            ' Display result.
            Console.WriteLine(arr.Length)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

Source: http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient-vbnet

Comment: Does DownloadData only ping the target url once ? I want to do open the page but make it invisible. Does DownloadData makes the same ?

Comment: Means, open the webpage in background. So it cant be seen, only in task manager you can see. But the problem with your solution is, it just send ping(hit) the url. Thats all. For example if there is a meta refreh on the target page to 3 min, it wont refresh.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to have a "invisible browser" in the background that is basically connected to the site - just like a user would be but without anything showing? How about setting a timer to run the download data every once in a while to get the website data? What is it from the website that you want to recieve?

Comment: I just want to open the page, or in programmatic word, navigate. This solution only send ping. webBrowser1.Navigate() does what I want, but it doesnt change headers. Hmm. Are there any other functions other than DownloadData() ? There is no need to set timer or etc. I hope I can explain what I want. Your solution is, like, using "ping targetwebsite.com" on cmd to get the site IP. It only goes once and comeback. I want the webpage opened in background.

Comment: But what on the page is it that you want to get? I don't see why you would just want to open a page (since it's invisible it won't be visible to the user) Is there information on the page that you'd like to get? 

The DownloadData method downloads the linked resource / webpage into a byte array. The array can be reversed and read into a string / file. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Its a user tracking software. In the page, there is a meta refresh code and it refreshes every 3 minutes. Thats why I want it to be keep alive. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to see for how long the user is using the software, where the user comes from (IP) and such? If so, collect the data and send it via a URL Parameter instead?

Comment: No, I want something to be keep-alive. The one posted in my question works, but as I said, I cant change user agent on that....